# Plotting Lagrange points

Tags: matlab, physics

I am trying to find the 5 Lagrange points of the Three-Body system by plotting the given potential function in Matlab. The only thing is that I'm not very good at programming. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. What I want to know is how to make this code give me a decent contour plot:

```
function Lagrange(a)


x = ( -10000: 1 : 10000);
y = ( -10000: 1 : 10000);
Potential = zeros(length(x));

for i = 1: length(x)
    for j = 1 : length(y)

    Potential(i,j) =  ( 1 - a ) / sqrt( ( x(i) - a )^2 + y(j)^2)  + a / sqrt( ( x(i) + 1    - a )^2 + y(j)^2 ) + ( x(i)^2 + y(j)^2 ) / 2 ;

    end

    j = 1;
end

contour(Potential);

xlabel('X axis'); 
ylabel('Y axis'); 
zlabel('Z axis');
```

Comment: Yeah please Disregard the limits of `x` and `y` vectors. They are distances measured as unit-less ratios with respect to the two masses' radii. They should vary from (-1.5, 1.5) likeSticky said. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the three-body problem is set up, the distance coordinates are normalized to `a`. Thus, you should pick `x` and `y` to be more like:

```
x = linspace(-1.5, 1.5, 1000);
y = linspace(-1.5, 1.5, 1000);
```

For the contour plot, you can use `meshgrid`, which allows you to avoid that for loop and plot a little easier:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
```

For the potential, try plotting 2U - this is called the [Jacobi constant](http://ccar.colorado.edu/asen5519/imd/documents/CRTBP_Handout.pdf) and is a bit more informative.

```
U = (1-a)./sqrt(Y.^2 + (X + a).^2) + ...
     a./sqrt(Y.^2 + (X + a - 1).^2) + ...
     0.5*(Y.^2 + X.^2);
Z = 2*U;
```

Finally, you'll need contours. You'll want to tweak these for your plot, but I used something like

```
c = [2.988:0.05:3.1, 3.2:0.2:5];
```

for the Earth-Moon system. Now, to plot, simply use `contourf` as follows:

```
figure
contourf(X, Y, Z, c)
colorbar
```

Also note that you can solve for the Lagrange points themselves analytically using the equations of motion - you may consider plotting these too, since the contours will only converge on the points but will never hit them.

Answer (score 1):

**Recommendations**

- Try using vector operations (rather than `for` loops), they're much faster. This is done by adding a '.' in front of the operator:  `*` becomes `.*`
- The matrix sizes suggested above may be a bit large, you'll likely run out of memory.  Try first with a smaller step size, then increase resolution.
- Your 'Z' axis in the Matlab `contour()` plot will be the color of the lines, so there is nothing to label.  Try `colorbar` instead.
- Use `...` to continue long statements on multiple lines.
- By convention, words starting with a capital letter are reserved for class definitions.

**Suggested Code**

```
function lagrange(a)
  n = 100000;
  stepsize = 100;
  [x,y] = ndgrid(-n:stepSize:n, -n:stepSize:n)
  potential = ( 1 - a ) ./ sqrt( ( x - a ).^2 + y.^2)  + ...
    a ./ sqrt( ( x + 1 - a ).^2 + y.^2 ) + ( x.^2 + y.^2 ) ./ 2 ;

  contour(x,y,potential)
  xlabel('X axis')
  ylabel('Y axis')
  colorbar
end
```